# send sms in phonegap app

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have been trying to get contact list and send sms to a contact in phonegap app.
I have tried with http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts
and https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin but these are not working.
Code does not execute after navigator.contacts.find method.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem.

JS Code

```
var contactFxn = {
getContact : function(){
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
var filter = ["displayName", "name"];
options.filter= "";
options.multiple=true;
navigator.contacts.find(filter, this.onSuccess, this.onError, options);
//console.log(options);
},
onSuccess : function(contacts){
    for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }  
},
onError : function(e){
    console.log(e);
}

};

function getContactTest() {
    contactFxn.getContact();
}
```

added plugin in config.xml as

```
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

tried for android as well

```
<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
</feature>
```

I am calling getContactTest() on a button click in html.I have checked it by putting alert in code, alert prints just before navigator.contacts.find and after that nothing happens.
Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad. It's quite impossible to understand what went wrong. Add some of your relevant code. See in eclipse logcat if any errors occur. Use the plugins one by one. first test if contact plugin is working, then test if sms is working.

Comment: @AtanuCSE I have updated the question with code.

Comment: @AtanuCSE can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I was using phonegap build and it was the reason that contact was not retrieved. Now I used command line build and all contacts are fetched and sms plugin is also working fine.